# Docker Build node:18-alpine fail with node-gyp-build text file is busy

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules, node-gyp

When use docker build node:18-alpine, we kept seeing issue with node-gyp-build that exit due to text file is busy.

Machine: x86 ubuntu-2204:2023.04.2

Docker version: 20.10.23

```
Command: node-gyp-build
Arguments: 
Directory: /app/xxxxxx/node_modules/xxxxxxx
Output:
/bin/sh: node-gyp-build: Text file busy"
```

tried few ways according to https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#node-gyp-alpine to add `--no-cache` but it won't help
Any suggestion on what could went wrong?
This works fine on node:16-alpine

Comment: Any luck resolving this?